# Let $H$ be the orthocenter of a triangle $ABC$, prove that $HA+HB+HC=a\cot A+b\cot B+c\cot C$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of a triangle $ABC$, prove that in any triangle $ABC$ the relation holds true: $$HA+HB+HC=a\cot A+b\cot B+c\cot C.$$
I found this problem in my 9th grade textbook and I have tried to change the form of: $a\cot A+b\cot B+c\cot C = 2(R+r)$, but this doesn't seem to solve it leaving me clueless. Can anyone help me with an idea that I can further continue to successfully solve this problem?

Comment: Here are some ideas, but dunno if any will actually work.

We need to introduce trigonometry into the relations, that means using some triangle relations. The law of cosines and sines are obvious choices, and you could combine them to get cotangent relations. 

$HA, HB, HC$ are part of the altitudes from the vertices. So you have right-angle triangles as well as relating them to the area of a triangle.

$HA, HB, c$ form a triangle, and $HA + HB + HC = \frac{1}{2}\left((HA + HB) + (HB + HC) + (HC + HA)\right)$.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1646259p10392320

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 cases to consider.

Case (i), when $\Delta ABC$ is an acute angled triangle.

[image]

In the figure, simple angle chasing shows that $\angle ABH=90^o-A$ and $\angle BHA=180^o-C$.

Applying Sine Rule on $\Delta ABH$

$$\frac{AH}{\sin (90^o-A)}=\frac{AB}{\sin (180^o-C)}$$

$$AH=\frac{c \cos A}{\sin C}$$

$$AH=\frac{a \cos A}{\sin A}= a \cot A$$

Similarly we can prove that $BH=b  \cot B$ and $CH=c \cot C$.

Case (ii), when $\Delta ABC$ is an obtuse angled triangle. Let's say $\angle A$ is obtuse.

[image]

Using the facts that $AEHF$ and $BCEF$ are concyclic, we can prove that $\angle AHB=C$, $\angle HBA=A-90^o$ and $\angle BAH=B+90^o$

Applying Sine Rule on $\Delta HAB$, we have

$$\frac{BH}{\sin (B+90^o)}=\frac{AB}{\sin C}=\frac{HA}{\sin (A-90^o)}.$$

From $$\frac{BH}{\sin (B+90^o)}=\frac{AB}{\sin C},$$ we have $$HB=\frac{c \cos B}{\sin C}=\frac{b \cos B}{\sin B}= b \cot B.$$

This is the same as the acute angled case.

But from  $$\frac{AB}{\sin C}=\frac{HA}{\sin (A-90^o)},$$ we have

$$HA=\frac{c (-\cos A) }{\sin C}=\frac{a (-\cos A) }{\sin A}=-a \cot A$$

Note the existence of the minus sign when $A$ is obtuse.

Thus when $A$ is obtuse, the result should be:

$$HA+HB+HC=-a\cot A+b\cot B+c\cot C$$

Or more generally, the result should be written as:
$$HA+HB+HC=a\lvert \cot A \rvert+b\lvert \cot B \rvert+c\lvert \cot C \rvert$$

Comment: Amazing solution, thank you for this elegant approach.

Comment: @David399 My first answer has neglected the case when $\Delta ABC$ is an obtuse angled triangle. I therefore rewrite my solution to include a second case. It turns out that the formula is a bit different for an obtuse angled triangle.